# Ipython unable to run `manage.py`

Tags: django

When I try to issue command to run Django shell with `ipython`, it prompt to type for help:

```
$ ipython manage.py shell

Type 'manage.py help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[contenttypes]
    remove_stale_contenttypes
```

However, I'm aware `ipython` is capable to run a module

```
cat expriment.py
print("run it with ipython")

ipython experiment.py
run it with ipython
```

What's the reason `ipython` unable to run `manage.py`?

Comment: try `python manage.py shell -i ipython`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know exactly why it doesn’t run as given in the question, but I can say that the django-extensions package will let you use an ipython shell.  It also adds a lot of other very useful stuff, notably profiling and a debugger with interactive tracebacks right in your browser.

Try:

```
pip install django-extensions
... add to config per instructions linked below ...
python manage.py shell_plus —ipython
```

Read more here http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed `ipython` in you `virtualenv`.

Either install it in your `virtualenv` or

use:

```
python manage.py shell -i ipython
```